# How to fit a poisson distribution on data using python or its libraries

Tags: python, statistics

I have some data in a CSV file to which I am trying to fit a Poisson distribution. I want to get the lambda for this data so that I can sample using this. How do I do this using python or any of its libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) has a single parameter - the mean, λ. So you don't need to 'fit' anything per se. Testing whether your data follows such a distribution is another question. Hope this helps.

```
import numpy as np
poisson_lambda = np.mean(data)
```

Comment: In Matlab you have a function called poissfit which returns the maximum likelihood estimate for lambda. I was wondering if something similar exists in python/its libraries?

Comment: @BAJUKA, I found this [article](https://statlect.com/fundamentals-of-statistics/Poisson-distribution-maximum-likelihood), which explains the maximum likelihood estimate for lambda is just the mean of the numbers.